# YOLOv8 model trained on coco.yaml and exported in onnx format

Tags: yolo

Is there already YOLOv8 model trained on coco.yaml dataset and exported in onnx filetype. I have searched it for a long time, but haven't found nothing. I don't have a computational capacity to create model myself.

Answer (score 1):

That's a easy task, you just want a pretrained yolov8 model.
Just do this:

Go to colab and run this:

```
!pip install ultralytics

from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
success = model.export(format="onnx")
```

And then you can download the model from the virtual machine.

That is all you need to do.
Another thing, there are several versions of yolov8 based on it's size, this is the verion nano, which is the smallest. There others like: yolov8s, yolov8m, yolov8l and yolov8x.

Just check the github for more info: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about using colab for training YOLO model.

Comment: You don't need to train, it's already trained, you just need to download it.